# Inserted rows vanish

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

We're having a problem on a wiki site (using mysql 5.5.9). There is a `text` table, and a `revision` table where `revision.rev_text_id` is a foreign key to `text.old_id` (there isn't a new one, ask wikimedia).

There is an `INSERT INTO text...`, then `INSERT INTO revision...` which uses the new `old_id`/`rev_text_id` received from the previous query.

The second query works, the first - I'm not sure. The thing is after the whole thing is gone through (with a few dozen more queries) the `revision` row is there, with a fresh new value in it's `rev_text_id` column.

However, the `text` row isn't there. Funny thing - the `text` table auto increment advances, as the next action skips a value for it's `old_id`, the missing value matching what we have in `revision` table.

Is there a chance the first query makes the auto increment index advance though the row isn't actually inserted? What causes this?

**ADDTITION**

When I copied the `INSERT INTO text` query from the logs and ran it on the server - it executed fine (row was added to table)

**EDIT**

Full queries are:

```
INSERT INTO text (old_id,old_text,old_flags) VALUES (NULL,'{text input by user}','utf8');
INSERT INTO `revision` (rev_id,rev_page,rev_text_id,rev_comment,rev_minor_edit,rev_user,rev_user_text,rev_timestamp,rev_deleted,rev_len,rev_parent_id,rev_sha1) VALUES (NULL,'{pageId}','{textId}','{comment}','{isMinor}','{userId}','{userName}','{TS}','{isDeleted}','{length}','{parentRevision}','{HASH}')"
```

Also, if relevant, `text` table is running InnoDB and `revision` is MyISAM.

**EDIT**

More information from logs:

Bad request

```
BEGIN
INSERT  INTO `text`
INSERT  INTO `revision`
UPDATE  `page` SET page_latest
INSERT  INTO `recentchanges`
INSERT  INTO `cu_changes`
SELECT  wl_user  FROM `watchlist` 
SELECT  user_id  FROM `user` 
SELECT  user_id,user_name,user_real_name,user_password,user_newpassword,user_newpass_time,user_email,user_touched,use
SELECT  ug_group  FROM `user_groups` 
SELECT  up_property,up_value  FROM `user_properties` 
SELECT  user_id,user_name,user_real_name,user_password,user_newpassword,user_newpass_time,user_email,user_touched,use
SELECT  ug_group  FROM `user_groups` 
SELECT  up_property,up_value  FROM `user_properties` 
SELECT  lc_value  FROM `l10n_cache` 
SELECT  lc_value  FROM `l10n_cache`
...
```

A few more `SELECT`s. Pause of activity for 2 sec, then the log has commands from a new user, no more queries from this user (on same thread).

An edit by same user to a different page, which went well:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `text`
INSERT INTO `revision`
UPDATE `page` SET page_latest
INSERT INTO `recentchanges`
INSERT INTO `cu_changes`
SELECT wl_user  FROM `watchlist` 
COMMIT
BEGIN
UPDATE `watchlist` SET wl_notificationtimestamp
COMMIT
BEGIN
SELECT user_id  FROM `user`
SELECT user_id,user_name,user_real_name,user_password,user_newpasswo
SELECT ug_group  FROM `user_groups` 
SELECT up_property,up_value  FROM `user_properties` 
SELECT *  FROM `user` 
SELECT up_property,up_value  FROM `user_properties` 
INSERT INTO `logging`
UPDATE `user` SET user_editcount=user_editcount+1
SELECT 1  FROM `user` 
UPDATE `user` SET user_touched = '20121227211743'
COMMIT
```

etc.

Comment: Need to see those two queries.

Comment: Is there a chance the first query makes the auto increment index advance though the row isn't actually inserted? What causes this?
yes, sure that might be what's going on. but can you tell me what engine are you using??

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan - Interestingly enough, `text` table is InnoDB, while the others are MyISAM. Probably a change we made ourselves a while back, not the original configuration.

Comment: @JNF I think you should make both InnoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a chance the first query makes the auto increment index advance though the row isn't actually inserted? What causes this?

Yes, when you try to insert a row in a table with an auto_increment column, the insertion will fail, but the auto_increment value will be incremented by 1.

If you decide to convert the tables to InnoDB, I suggest you to use transactions. This way if one the queries fails none of them will be inserted.

Comment: I understand `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will act accordingly (though there wasn't really an insert)

Comment: There is actually a `BEGIN` before it all starts, I couldn't find a matching `COMMIT` in the logs

Comment: Transactions only works with some storage engines, but they don't work with MyISAM. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

Comment: Problem not solved yet, but information was helpful. Thank you